# What is nss-myhostname? And why is it not installable?

Tags: apt, package-management, dmesg

`dmesg` shows the line

```
systemd-hostnamed[3964]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. 
Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
```

But

`sudo apt-get install nss-myhostname`

says

```
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
E: Paket nss-myhostname kann nicht gefunden werden.
```

...meaning "nss-myhostname not found".

Why? Do I have to react on the dmesg message?

Comment: Does the warning continue after `sudo apt-get libnss-myhostname`?

Comment: I've the same alarm on ubuntu 14.10 desktop edition and after to install that package I don't see that any more

Answer (score 30):

There is a [confirmed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1277608) logged against systemd-hostnamed saying;

> Since nss-myhostname was rejected as being the right approach in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnss-myhostname/+bug/1162478/comments/6 , we should not print the warning message in the LTS release, even if hostnamed doesn't currently modify /etc/hosts.
>
> Can we please patch this warning out to prevent users from thinking something is wrong on their system and leading them to install libnss-myhostname?.

Even though it may avoid the warning, you may not want to install libnss-myhostname for that purpose only.

Any body seeing the message

```
 systemd-hostnamed
[16495]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
```

**must read this** https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1277608 **this** https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnss-myhostname/+bug/1162478/comments/6 before installing the nss-myhostname package.

Comment: so I shouldn't do anything?

Comment: As well as the above linked discussions, I would strongly suggest anyone considering installing libnss-myhostname also read [this Debian bug report against exim4](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=833296) that was eventually discovered to have been caused by libnss-myhostname subtly misconfiguring name services in a way that cause exim to fail to deliver local mail.  You do not want this package on your system.

Answer (score 27):

From [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/nss-myhostname.html):

> nss-myhostname is a plugin for the GNU Name Service Switch (NSS) functionality of the GNU C Library (glibc) providing hostname resolution for the locally configured system hostname as returned by gethostname(2)
>   There are two possible solutions:

- You may have not (or incorrectely) configured your hostname in `/etc/hosts`. Correcting that may resolve this.
- Another way, as the warning suggests, is to install nss-myhostname, which is referred to in debian as `libnss-myhostname`. This is only a workaround, not the suggested solution to the relevant bug. Install using:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libnss-myhostname
  ```

<sub>Source: [13.04 dmesg: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2148342)</sub>

Comment: Is there a way to merge answers?  I feel your answer does not take into consideration what yoyoma2 highlights in that it is NOT recommended to install that package purely for the purposes of preventing dbus messages requesting it.   It is a known bug as yoyoma2 highlights.   yoyoma2 also explains the "Why? Do I have to react on the dmesg message?" part of the question asked.  I can not see how to edit your answer without completely changing it!

Comment: Also the ubuntu forums thread linked too in no way shape or form recommends installing (though it is suggested but with no feedback or confirmation or explanation) the package you suggest is good idea.   reading the thread suggests other workarounds and explains why!

Answer (score 6):

I doubt you will want to install those libraries. Seen as it's nothing more than a nuisance you can simply silence the message.

Create a new config file in `/etc/rsyslog.d/` and tell the message to be dropped:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/rsyslog.d/20-systemd-hostnamed.conf
```

Add the following single line:

```
:msg, contains, "Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed." stop
```

Save and close, and restart the daemon:

```
$ sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Job done. You can make sure that the messages are being dropped by intentionally trying to spam your `syslog`:

```
$ logger -t TEST "Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed."
```

The message should be silently dropped.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue.

Not a long-term solution by any means - but one that suited me - was to remove the old host names attached to my localhost in /etc/hosts/ as these are no longer used.

The message is no longer served.