# Help Debugging Wireless Issue

Tags: wireless, lenovo

I have a Lenovo e330 notebook with broadcom bcm4313 802.11 bgn wireless adapter.

I have configured it for dual boot Windows 8/Ubuntu 14.04.

It has problem connecting to wireless, and this problem is the same in Windows or Ubuntu. 
The wireless will not connect after many tries. Then after a restart (or two or more) the wireless will then connect. 
I keep restarting the PC until it connects.

I found that if it connects in Windows, and I change to Ubuntu, it will connect in Ubuntu. If it won't connect in Windows, it won't connect in Ubuntu either.

I have already turned power management off.

Tried many things in Windows 8 such as disabling Lenovo software, n channel and ipv6. But same problem in Ubuntu I can't see how it can be a Lenovo problem.

dmesg output when not working: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9577308/

Comment: @chili555 Why do you think this is a duplicate? I don't doubt it, but I can't close a question without being pretty confident and these two questions don't exactly look or sound alike. Wireless isn't my forté :)

Comment: He has the same device, the same symptoms and will benefit from the same fix!

Comment: I am unsure if it's the same problem - I can connect successfully using wl drivers. The other person seems to not be able to connect at all.  But I have tried their fix, and will see if this fix resolves it. I will also try this fix in Windows and see if it fixes Windows as well.

Comment: Maybe I was confused. Your question says: "The wireless will not connect after many tries."

Comment: No problem :-), the next sentence says "Then after a restart (or two or more) the wireless will then connect. I keep restarting the PC until it connects. ". Well the network name wasn't showing up yesterday at all, I had to restart PC 3 times before it showed up, then I could connect. I'm not sure if it's a separate or related issue.

Comment: @chili555 In case you didn't get the OP's reply.

Comment: @James152 That's not what I'd characterize as connecting successfully. I stand by my proposed solution. Thanks you, @Seth!

Answer (score 0):

> nss-myhostname is a plugin for the GNU Name Service Switch (NSS)
>   functionality of the GNU C Library (glibc) providing hostname
>   resolution for the locally configured system hostname as returned by
>   gethostname(2) There are two possible solutions:

- You may have not (or incorrectely) configured your hostname in /etc/hosts. Correcting that may resolve this.
- Another way, as the warning suggests, is to install nss-myhostname, which is referred to in debian as libnss-myhostname, so install using:

`sudo apt-get install libnss-myhostname`

Source : https://askubuntu.com/a/453084/69743