# How to install drivers for Mightex camera?

Tags: drivers

I have a Mightex camera and have been given the source code for the drivers by the company. They have been very helpful so far but was hoping to ask here and understand what's going on. This is the first time I have to manually install / compile drivers like this so please excuse my ignorance.

In the readme file it says I should do the following:

```
make
make install
```

and that should be it.

It doesn't say I should but I run it as root (ie use `sudo`)

When I run `sudo make` I get a bunch of warnings about variables not used etc (let me know if this is needed so I can post) Also, I then proceed to run `sudo make install` and get the following error:

```
/sbin/depmod -aeE
/sbin/depmod: option requires an argument -- 'E'

make: *** [install] Error 1
```

The man page of `depmod` says:

> When combined with the -e option, this reports any symbol versions supplied by modules that do not match with the symbol versions provided by the kernel in its Module.symvers. This option is mutually incompatible with -F.

But not sure what to do with that information. I have a `Module.symvers` file but it's empty.

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm a bit at a loss here.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in order to compile a driver from source code, you need to install the prerequisites build-essential and linux-headers-generic. Then the usual procedure is:

```
cd ~/directory/with/sourcecode  <--for example, ~/Downloads/mightex
make
```

And if there are no errors:

```
sudo make install
sudo depmod -a
```

Warnings are often acceptable; errors are not.

It would be helpful to see the result of this sequence. If possible, paste the results here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

It would also be helpful to try the source code ourselves. Is there a link where we can download it?

Comment: No. it's not available anywhere online. :( I spoke to the company and they were very helpful and sent it over. I can post the output of the error messages though. Also, after running `sudo depmod -a` do I need to restart for it to work?

Comment: output from `sudo make` http://paste.ubuntu.com/9564183/
output from `sudo make install` http://paste.ubuntu.com/9564193/

Comment: I suggest you try sudo depmod -a followed by sudo modprobe Mightex. There were many warnings but no errors.

Comment: no messages or erros but I still don't get a /dev/video1 or smth similar...

Comment: Please check: dmesg | grep -i might

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9564442/ should I install nss-myhostname? as per here http://askubuntu.com/questions/453072/what-is-nss-myhostname-and-why-is-it-not-installable

Comment: I installed `libnss-myhostname` the warnings went away at the output of `dmesg` but still no /dev/video1 or smth like that.

Comment: Can you start a video application like cheese and see the camera or its output? You might get some clues starting cheese from the terminal.

Comment: the problem is I can only access the /dev/video0 which is my webcam, I don't know where to find the mightex camera

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19596/discussion-between-evan54-and-chili555).