# Driver written and tested for ubuntu 12.04 doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04, how can I make it work for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, webcam

I was wondering if anyone had any tips for the following problem. I have a Mightex USB webcam and the drivers I have been given (including source code under GNU GPL) say they have been tested and work on Ubuntu 12.04. I'm running ubuntu 14.04 and it seems they don't work.

Is there a solution to this? What information would I need to provide to help someone help me.

I've asked a related question about this here:
[How to install drivers for Mightex camera?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563080/how-to-install-drivers-for-mightex-camera)

Answer (score 0):

You do not. Linux kernel intentionally breaks its ABI each release, making drivers incompatible.

Comment: given that they're open would I be able to reverse engineer certain things? I mean I have the source and I am asked to compile it, which I've done and it loads ie in `dmesg` I can find it but there is no `/dev/video*` path and I can't access it through vlc or smth similar